# Function overloading with generics in Java

Tags: java, overloading

I have a problem I cant figure out. 
With these classes:

- [PrimitiveToken](http://www.copypastecode.com/183941/)
- [GBVariable](http://www.copypastecode.com/183926/)
- GBFloat:

```
public class GBFloat extends GBVariable<Float> { 
   public GBFloat(String name, Float value) {  super(name, value); }
}
```

- PlusToken:

```
@Override
public GBVariable<?> eval() {
    return sum(a.eval(),b.eval());
}

public static GBFloat sum(GBFloat a, GBFloat b) {
    System.out.println("float added");
    return new GBFloat("tmp", a.getValue()+b.getValue());
}

public static GBVariable<?> sum(GBVariable<?> a, GBVariable<?> b) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Adding variables of types "+a.getClass().getSimpleName()+" and "+b.getClass().getSimpleName()+" is not supported.");
}
```

When I execute the eval method in the PlusToken while while a and b are of type GBFloat Java still chooses the `sum(GBVariable<?> a, GBVariable<?> b)` method and throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding variables of types GBFloat and GBFloat is not supported.
```

Shouldn't he choose the more specific method? if I cast a.eval() and b.eval() into GBVariables first it works fine. Why is that and how can I solve this problem elegantly?

a and b are declared like that:

```
new PrimitiveToken<GBFloat>(new GBFloat("tmp",Float.parseFloat("15.0")))
```

Comment: Please condense your code to the **bare minimum** required to demonstrate the problem, and paste it directly into your question.

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration of variables `a` and `b`, which is the most critical piece of the puzzle.  If it's `GBVariable<?> a = new GBFloat(...)` then the behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shown the declarations of `a` and `b` I'm going to guess you have

```
GBVariable<?> a = new GBFloat(...);
GBVariable<?> b = new GBFloat(...);
```

In which case the behavior you describe is correct.  Function dispatch (binding a call to a method) occurs at compile time, using the static types of the arguments.  Not the runtime types.

Answer (score 0):

Method over loading is done compile time, not runtime. This is why you get different results when casting the variables directly.